# Access corrupted SSD

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, windows-10, filesystem-corruption

I installed the latest Nvidia-driver on my SSD 850 Evo OS-Partition running Win10 and after that left the PC and went eating, not having it restarted, because still downloading iTunes.

When returning to the PC, I just saw a black screen with a white cursor. I restarted the PC and just got the same window, without seeing the BIOS.

I did a CMOS-reset and after that, I got into BIOS-screen and then Windows told me, it had the problem "Inaccessible boot device". I then went into Sys-repair.

Automatic repair didn't work, but safe boot did. After that, everything was normal, I restarted once without problem, but the second time, the screen went black again and now I didn't even have a cursor and the PC began restarting all the time.

I never got a audio-signal, CMOS-reset didn't help anymore.

I then took the SSD out the PC and tried using it with two other PCs working fine with their hard drives and got the same problem as before, when booting with the SSD.

Now my question is: How can I access the data on the SSD or at least reset it?

Update: I managed to connect the SSD with a PC running Ubuntu. The "Drives-App" tells me the correct name for the drive, but can't tell what's on it. I also can't mount it with the App and can't see it in the files-overview.
I tried mounting it with:

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/windows
```

but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Why don't you mount it as second hard drive to browse it?

Comment: The PCs don't even boot into BIOS when the SSD is plugged in.

Comment: How are you connecting it as secondary drive?